# How to simulate disabled button with custom button tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, javascriptmvc

jsbin link: http://jsbin.com/axevid/2 <- open using Webkit browser (Chrome or Safari)

When regular button is disabled, all events are disabled too. I created a custom tag (part of the requirement of the project) for a custom button. But how can I make it so that it disables binded events when the button is disabled and get them back once enabled?

I'm using Javascript MVC. I think I saw a function, which disables events, but I forgot where it was.

**EDIT**: The code should be kind of a plug-in, which should work on all custom buttons. In other words, I don't want to include if statement in each binded event. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you create the control, you also need to add event listeners to it for the events you want to prevent (`"click"` and `"keypress"`, probably). Then, in the handlers, call `event. stopImmediatePropagation()` if you want to prevent anyone else from seeing the event.

For example:

```
btn.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    if (btn.disabled) {
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    }
});
```

Comment: I've edited the question. I don't want to include if statement in each event listener, but more like to have a general code, which I can include in all files, and which cancels other events.

Answer (score 0):

This will work: http://jsbin.com/axevid/3

I made changes in the following part:

```
$(document).delegate('abutton', 'click', function(e){
  if($(this).attr('disabled')){
    e.preventDefault();
    return;
  }
  alert("Custom button");

});
```

Comment: I've edited the question. I don't want to include if statement in each event listener, but more like to have a general code, which I can include in all files, and which cancels other events.

Answer (score 0):

Does you mean (as I understood from your request)

```
$(function() {
$("abutton").each(function() {
if($(this).attr("disabled")) {
e.preventDefault();
return;
});
});
```

Comment: I've edited the question. I don't want to include if statement in each event listener, but more like to have a general code, which I can include in all files, and which cancels other events.